# Django Nullable Foreign Key not Working

Tags: django, foreign-keys, nullable

I have two models formatted as follows:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    # ...

class Message(models.Model):
    # ...
    attachment = models.ForeignKey(Attachment, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    # ...
```

I have tried various solutions found every where online...but cannot make it work!
Here are some of the combinations I have tried:

- blank=True
- null=True
- blank=True, null=True
- default=None
- blank=True, null=True, default=None
- etc.

I keep getting the following error whenever I try to save a message with no attachment.

```
IntegrityError: myapp_message.attachment_id may not be NULL
```

I am using SQLite if that is significant. Why isn't what I am doing working?

Comment: did you modify your model after doing `syncdb`? If that's the case, you should delete your table and syncdb again.

Comment: That worked great! Please post the 'delete your table' solution and I will accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you modify your model after doing `syncdb`? If that's the case, you should delete your table and `syncdb` again.